# Python variable passing between procedures

Tags: python, list, variables, if-statement, procedures

I'm working on a code that firstly checks first letters of words from a list and letter counts only those that are letter 'U'

Currently I'm facing issue with:

1. how to make main procedure to pass the input to check_first_letter
2. how to search the check_first_letter results and count them

code:

```
def check_first_letter(w):
    return [s[:1] for s in w]

def measure_udacity(methodToRun):
    result = methodToRun()
    return result

print measure_udacity(['Dave','Sebastian','Katy'])
```

Comment: Just pass in the return value of the main function as an argument to `check_first_letter`. `ret = main(); check_first_letter(ret)` or in one step: `check_first_letter(main())`

Comment: what do you mean 'to pass the input to check_first_letter'? 'input' from where? do you want to pass any input from stdinput or do you want to run script from terminal with some parameters (`python run.py dave sebastian katy`) and catch this arguments in your code?

Comment: I want to measure_udacity to pass the input to check_first_letter and after printing first letters pass them back to measure_udacity to count.

Comment: the answer to the first question is obvious. `measure_udacity` gets input to the `methodToRun`. `methodToRun` - it is name of input variable for the function `measure_udacity`. So you should pass it through to `check_first_letter`. the second question isn't clear. do you really need that printing first letters was the function with name `measure_udacity` and counter of 'U' letter was function with the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating things.
Try this:

```
def measure_udacity(names):
    for n in names:
        if n[0] =='U':
            print (n, len(n))

measure_udacity(['Dave','Sebastian','UKaty'])
```